# Array To Button C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently creating a Deal or No Deal in C# and so far I'm doing fine until I'm now stuck in how can I passed the values of an array to the buttons in random. This is the screenshot of what I am doing

[image]

This is my class:

```
int[] cases = new int[26] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
    int[] amounts = new int[26] {1, 3, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000};
```

I want to pass the values of my amounts in the buttons in random order, so that when the user clicks on the button, it will show to him/her the value of that button. I've already got the logic but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Tie the onClick event of each button to the same event handler that has your logic implemented. Change the state of the button once it's clicked to prevent another click. Decide how you want to present the results of the click to the user, a simple message box could work, telling them what they found in the case. Or, you could get fancy and change the text of the button to the value they've found. Either way, it's basically one function in the code behind.

Comment: that is what I want to do but my problem is I don't know how to put an array value to my buttons

Comment: You mean you don't understand arrays? That's a different question, ask that as a new question. If you understand `myButton.Text = "2"` but you don't understand how to get from there to an array, you'll need another question for that.  The answers can get quite long and really don't have anything to do with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm idunno but may do this..

(CORRECT ME IF IM WRONG **:)** )

like [Ron Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4318814/ron-thompson) said link all click event of the buttons to one event handler

then do this

```
private void magic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bool isStop = false;
      Random rand = new Random;

      while (isStop == false)
      {
         int val = rand.Next(1,27);

         if (amounts[val] != 0) //if 0 then do not show this amount coz it is already been used
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Value is " + amounts[val]);
            amounts[val] = 0;
            isStop = true;
         }
         else
         {
           //continue the loop until unused amount is detected
         }
      }  
    }
```